# Followers - mongodb query check

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have 2 collections in my database. One is called User

```
{
   _id: storeUserId,
   name: ...,
   etc
}
```

the other one called Following

```
{
   userId: ...,
   followingUserId: ...
}
```

the userId is the current user id and the followingUserId is the id that  current user wants to follow.

For example, in User collection I have:

```
{
  _id: userIdOne,
   etc
},
{
  _id: userIdTwo,
  etc
}
```

and in Following collection I have:

```
{
  userId: userIdThousand,
  followingUserId: userIdTwo
}
```

When I run find query

```
db.bios.find();
```

I get

```
   {
    "_id": userIdTwo,
    "username": "random27005688"
},
{
    "_id": userIdThree
    "username": "random232111"
},
{
    "_id": userIdOne
    "username": "random2702"
}
]
```

The result is what I want but I want to add a 'isFollowed' field to each result item to check following status. I have a user id let say: 'userIdThousand' which I want to use it to check against each result item based on my Following collection. E.g,

```
check if userIdThousand is following userIdOne
check if userIdThousand is following userIdTwo, etc.
```

Below is my expected result. Thanks!

```
[
{
    _id: userIdTwo,
    "username": "random27005688",
    "isFollowed": true
},
{
    "_id": userIdThree
    "username": "random232111",
    "isFollowed": false
},
   {
    "_id": userIdOne
    "username": "random2702",
     "isFollowed": false
},
]
```

Comment: Can you post the output you want from the query

Comment: I think I have it in my question already. Basically I just need a "isFollwed" field to check follow status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to get the data from second collection matching by `followingUserId` then you can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to get only followers with particular `_id` and check if new array has any elements (using [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html)) which means that user is followed by other user:

```
db.User.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _id: { $ne: "userIdOne" }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Following",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "followingUserId",
            as: "followers"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            followers: {
                $filter: { input: "$followers", as: "follower", cond: { $eq: [ "$$follower._id", "userIdOne" ] } }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            username: 1,
            isFollowed: { $gt: [ { $size: "$followers" }, 0 ] }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Oh great! Can you please explain to me what this line does: isFollowed: { $gt: [ { $size: "$followers" }, 0 ] }

Comment: `$size` returns length of an array so if that length is greater than zero (`$gt`) then it means that user is followed by someone

Comment: in $lookup, is there a way that I can put in ''userIdOne" so it will check userIdOne against all the user in return result from $match. The reason is because isFollowed always return false because isFollowed is empty in $lookup. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinVuD I'm not sure if I understand correctly but I guess you can achieve that modifying `$match`

Comment: All I want is to fetch all the user info in User collection and then use an userId that I have to check against each query result to see if that userId follow any user info in the return query.

Comment: So it seems like you dont need first $match, modfied my answer

Comment: and which part can I put the userId that I have to check? Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: @KevinVuD just to clarify: you want to get all users but isFollowed should show if particular user is followed by any other user or you want to know if each user is followed by one other particular (for instance "userOne") ?

Comment: I want to get all users and after that I want to use this example user id 'fsdfds2432' to check against each result item based on my Following collection to see if 'fsdfds2432'  is following them. I hope it is clear and please let me know if it isn't

Comment: I just edited my question and I hope it is much clearer now.

Comment: @KevinVuD thank you, now I get that, edited my answer, you need additional `$filter` to do that

Comment: if it is possible, can you please explain the filter function? Thank you so much!

Comment: @KevinVuD it takes an array, checks condition specified under `cond` and returns another array. $addFields overwrites followers array in this case. Check mongo docs if you need examples: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could split it into two step.

## 1. query User and get the result

for example, you get a user.

```
{
    _id: userIdTwo,
    "username": "random27005688",
}
```

## 2. query Following and get if the user has been followed.

such as

```
has_followed=db.Following.find({"userId":userIdTwo}).count()
```

not the best solution but it might help u.